# Understanding the proof of the division algorithm for F[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

The proof of the division algorithm for polynomials over a field F is shown here:
[image]

The part I don't quite get is "let r(x) be an element of minimal degree in S." Are we assuming that there is only one element of minimal degree or are we just randomly choosing one? Because the proof shows that this chosen element is the one that works, but if we had randomly choose another element that is also of minimal degree, then that one would've also worked since the rest of the proof is the same. But then, the rest of the proof that follows proves there is only one unique r(x) that works (I have not attached that part of the proof here), so is the proof also proving that there is only one element of minimal degree?

Comment: They say "an element of minimal degree". I suspect they mean exactly what they say, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: OK, suppose there are two of them $r_1,r_2$. Then by what you have proved the degree of $r_1-r_2$ is less than $m$. But it is clear that $g$ divides $r_1-r_2$. This forces $r_1-r_2=0$ and so the remainder is unique.

Comment: That first half of the proof is showing only  *existence* of the quotient and remainder. Presumably the proof continues by later showing their *uniqueness* also - as claimed.